# Problem in connecting to a server waiting for a TCP request using ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, network, at-commands, tcp-ip, internet

I'm using ESP8266 for connecting to a `appspot-preview.l.google.com` server which listens for TCP request and answers back a number (it's for training purposes).

Problem is from my location, I can't connect to the website properly even from my browser. Firefox and Chrome take about ~40 seconds to render the page (which has a list of people who issued TCP request to that server).

Now, my specific problem lies in `("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"%s\",80\r\n", IPaddress)`. ESP8266 quickly replies a "`ERROR`" after trying to establish a TCP connection to that IP.

**1-** I want ESP8266 to wait and try connecting to the website in the same way my browser does (after ~40 seconds). How can I do this?

**2-** There is a "TCP keep alive" switch in the `AT+CIPSTART` command from official "[ESP8266 AT Instruction Set](http://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf)":
[image: Establish TCP Connection from ESP8266 AT Instruction Set]
Is this option relevant to my problem? Why is there a comma *inside* the brackets?

Thanks

Comment: The comma separates the parameters, as the TCP keep alive is an optional parameter, that last comma is optional as well. It is not needed if the last parameter is not used. That is why it is inside the brackets.

Comment: @BenceKaulics So the bracket is not needed as well? Is this a valid use case: `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","1.2.3.4",80,60` ? Does this force ESP8266 to wait 60 seconds and listen for a response, then after that issue `ERROR` if any?

Comment: why have you not tried setting the option before you posted the question?

Comment: @jsotola I've tested a bracket and a comma inside bracket. It gave ERROR. I couldn't know whether my AT commands was wrong or not

Comment: Rather than struggling with appspot-preview.l.google.com why don't you run a TCP server on your PC? I've used [Hercules](https://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) and found it really useful for testing things like the ESP8266.

Comment: Keepalive is not the answer, what you want is to change the connection (and perhaps session) timeout, and for that you need documentation and/or source for the ESP8266 TCP/IP stack.  But if it's taking 40 seconds from other devices, that server or connection provider are probably not the right choices.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Also I can't ping the IP in my Windows cmd (timeout). And how can I access that documentations you mentioned? Is it doable in AT commands?

Comment: @ChrisStratton BTW, I managed to get response from that google webservice server! I used a service called `www.hurl.it`. Just pass your parameters and it does GET instead of you, and prints the response. Very effective. Keeping this post here if anyone has problems connecting to such servers in specific locations. Hope it helps someone

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator, if that solved your problem, then post it as an answer and then accept it

Comment: @jsotola I used a browser-based third party solution. Actually I want ESP8266 to wait n seconds in trying to establish a TCP connection. ChrisStratton hinted that I should change connection or session timeout but I don't know how